# Inspecting element is different from what is returned by BeautifulSoup/Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make price scrapers for several websites, but I've come across a problem for one specific website. When inspecting the price, the decimal shows "56", but when I download the HTML with BeautifulSoup it instead returns 16. The same problem also occurs for other products.

Below you can see my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

myProxy = {"http"  : "http://10.120.118.49:8080", "https"  : 
"https://10.120.118.49:8080"}

url = 'https://shop.rewe.de/coca-cola-4x1-5l/PD6731201'

page = requests.get(url, proxies = myProxy)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

predecimal = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'pd-price__predecimal'})
predec = predecimal.text.strip()

separator = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'pd-price__separator'})
sep = separator.text.strip()

decimal = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'pd-price__decimal'})
dec = decimal.text.strip()

price = str(predec) + str(sep) + str(dec)

print(price)
```

The above code returns 5,16 while the price shown on the website is 5,56. For some other websites I successfully used Selenium instead, but in this case it still returns the same number. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible that `5,56` is just in your browser cache, because they just start started a sale today or something?

Comment: I don't think so, as the price has been the same for some time. It also shows the same price on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, I also tried with Selenium, using the following code:

```
driver.get('https://shop.rewe.de/coca-cola-4x1-5l/PD6731201')
xpath = '//*[@class="pd-PriceInformation"]/mark'
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
for p in price:
    print(p.text)
```

This returns "ab 5, 16 €", so basically the same as when using BeautifulSoup. When trying the same code for the website https://shop.rewe.de/vio-bio-limo-orange-4x1l/PD2455462 it instead returns "ab 5, 96 €", which is also wrong, as the price is 5,56 in this case as well.